# Ошибка Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, gradle

Получаю такую ошибку при сборе проекта:

> `Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/android/gms/internal/zzas.class`

Как это исправить? Я так понимаю, что проблема в build.gradle, в библиотеке gms. Но не могу понять какая именно строчка дает этот конфликт:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile project(':react-native-twitter-signin')
    compile project(':react-native-linkedin-login')
    compile project(':react-native-google-signin')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-spinkit')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.1.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.instabug.library:instabug:3+'
    compile(project(':react-native-google-signin')) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    compile 'org.piwik.sdk:piwik-sdk:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.12.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: compile project(':react-native-linkedin-login') и compile project(':react-native-twitter-signin') продублировано

Comment: О, точно! Сейчас попробую по-новому собрать проект!

Comment: Пересобрала проект, но ошибка все равно осталась!

Comment: запустите `gradlew app:dependencies --configuration releaseCompileClasspath` и добавьте вывод

Comment: compile project(':react-native-google-signin') продублировано, причем один раз без эксклуда, а второй раз с.